# Unable to pass HTTP response to argument in Argo DAG workflow

Tags: argo-workflows

I am trying to capture the response of a HTTPTemplate request and pass it to the next task within a DAG workflow, but the argument to the next template is not being populated/ expanded.
The problem isn't necessarily the capture of the HTTP response (although this is what I'm actually trying to test), it seems to be the 'injection' of the argument within my second step.

This is the worklow, with the two templates included:

```
metadata:
  name: blimin-annoying
  namespace: argo
  labels:
    example: 'true'
spec:
  entrypoint: passing
  templates:
  - name: passing
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: step1
        template: execute
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: schema
            value: kunveno
          - name: method
            value: GET
      - name: step2
        depends: step1
        template: echo
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: '{{tasks.step1.outputs.parameters.response}}'
#--------------------------
  - name: execute
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: schema
        - name: method
    outputs:
      parameters:
        - name: response
          value: '{{outputs.result}}'
    http:
      method: '{{inputs.parameters.method}}'
      url: 'http://host.minikube.internal:3007/query/$event_stores?countOnly=true'
      headers:
        - name: query-schema
          value: '{{inputs.parameters.schema}}'
        - name: content-type
          value: application/json
#--------------------------
  - name: echo
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: message
    container:
      image: 'docker/whalesay:latest'
      command:
        - cowsay
      args:
        - '{{inputs.parameters.message}}'
```

And the output I get, regardless of how I seem to quote/ specify the 'message' argument of step2.

```
loegnhfdn1-1675440399:  _________________________________________
loegnhfdn1-1675440399: / {{tasks.step1.outputs.parameters.resp \
loegnhfdn1-1675440399: \ onse}}                                  /
loegnhfdn1-1675440399:  -----------------------------------------
```

It's as if the variable is being treated as a plain String.
Ideally I'd like to pass the response as a file to the next step, but am currently stuck at this basic stage.

Note; This is on v3.2.4 2021-11-18

Answer (score 1):

After coding up my template creation through the JavaSDK, I accidentally changed the output.parameters.name to 'result', compared to 'response' as posed in the question. This 'typo' actually fixed the issue of passing the response to the next step.
It is unclear whether 'response' is a reserved word, or 'result' is, but the following now works.
Hopefully of use to someone else!

```
metadata:
  name: now-working
  namespace: argo
  labels:
    example: 'true'
spec:
  entrypoint: passing
  templates:
  - name: passing
    dag:
      tasks:
      - name: step1
        template: execute
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: schema
            value: public
          - name: method
            value: GET
      - name: step2
        depends: step1
        template: echo
        arguments:
          parameters:
          - name: message
            value: '{{tasks.step1.outputs.parameters.result}}'
#--------------------------
  - name: execute
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: schema
        - name: method
    outputs:
      parameters:
        - name: response
          value: '{{outputs.result}}'
    http:
      method: '{{inputs.parameters.method}}'
      url: 'http://host.minikube.internal:3007/query/$event_stores?countOnly=true'
      headers:
        - name: query-schema
          value: '{{inputs.parameters.schema}}'
        - name: content-type
          value: application/json
#--------------------------
  - name: echo
    inputs:
      parameters:
        - name: message
    container:
      image: 'docker/whalesay:latest'
      command:
        - cowsay
      args:
        - '{{inputs.parameters.message}}'
```